# Nginx : detect mobile and forward to desktop

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have a problem i want to detect the domain and the device and forward the response to the desktop, www server section of nginx. With a rewrite this is done but the problem is the url, is cleared and substitute with my url, the configuration is the following :

```
  server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    #this detects any domain
    server_name  ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
    root /home/someone/main;
    index index.html index.htm;

    set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

    # this regex string is actually much longer to match more mobile devices
    if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|webOS|Windows Phone)') {
        set $mobile_rewrite perform;
    }

    location / {
       if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
           rewrite ^ http://m.someone.domain.com$request_uri? redirect;
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

I tried a different approach with an alias to the path in so of the m.someone.domain.com code section but this doesn't work inside the if witch is inside the location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying your if block in following way.

```
location / {
       if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
           return 301 http://m.someone.domain.com$request_uri;
       }
}
```

As you are using rewrite rule as redirect so above may work. Also rewrites are heavier.

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
   if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
       rewrite ^http://m.someone.domain.com$request_uri? / permanent;
   }
}
```

Try this it might work for u